# Image is loaded much too big

Tags: android

I have a nexus 7 tablet with 1900 x 1200 resolution. I try to create an `ImageButton` with `wrap_content` but the created `ImageButton` is much too big and i dont know why.

This is the layout i use:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/main_button_fog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_fog"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i start my Application it looks like that:

[image]

As a reminder: the width of nexus 7 tablet is 1200 px. The with of my image is 397 px so it should be much smaller. Why is the Image loaded here so big?

Comment: you probably want to use `android:src` instead of `android:background` (scaleType works on `src`, not on `background`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I didn't try this**, but i think that it can work. But if i can say a thing, put the value of width and height as wrap_content if you want that image will have the maximum dimensions is not useful. If you want to scale the image as the size of the screen you have to use also Java part. Tell me if this doesn't  work by the way.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/main_button_fog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="android:color/transparent"
    android:src="@drawable/custom_button_fog"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_description"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: its this + the answer of @user1194268. so i also had to place the views in xhdpi folder